# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: E11000 duplicate key error collection: metalab_development.demands index: sn_1 dup key: { : null } (11000)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Why I encounter the error 'duplicate key'? Actually, I have added the following line in my code:

```
index({ sn: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true})
```

Then I type the command:

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

The error appeared, which confuse me.

Comment: delete unique statement this command throw exception unique means not sport duplicate but sparse means sport duplicate field in indexed filed

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing out that you have documents within your collection that have duplicate keys. This is due to your index requiring their to be unique records for that key.

If you do not need unique records: remove the unique:true from that statement

If you do need unique records: search for documents with duplicated keys and update them

A note on sparse, it means it'll only index if the key exists in the document, and ignore documents that do not have the key [sparse docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/)

**Update:**

If I am reading the error correctly, the duplicate key may be 'null'. As you are using sparse, if you [unset](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-persistence/#atomic) the field where the current entry is null, your index should then work.

Comment: I am inserting new data in the database but some of it already exists so I am getting this error, I am doing batch insert, how can I ignore this? If I put exception handler then it inserts some data and some data is left

Comment: What do you want to happen with the duplicates? You have a few choices. In your exception handler you can update the existing docs with the new data or change the key that is docs you wish to insert so they do not clash with existing ones.